# Django -- Only Displaying Objects A User Created

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-urls

I'm building a Django app with a legacy DB. I have one model, LIST, which is from that legacy DB and cannot really be changed. I am using the standard Django user model as well. Ideally, this is what I want to happen. A user signs up, and after signup is redirected to create a new LIST object. Once that new list object is created, the user is redirect to a view containing data from that LIST object they just created. One subsequent logins, the user is taken back to the view containing the data of the LIST object they created. As of right now I have extended the user model like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    list_id = models.OneToOneField(List, null=True)

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

My ListForm looks like this:

```
class ListForm(ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'text-error'
    required_css_class = 'text-required'

    class Meta:
        model = models.List
        fields = ('t_handle', 'facebook_id', 'pinterest_id', 'yelp_id', 'foursquare_id', 'yipit_id', )
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UserSignupForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            g = Group.objects.get(name='test_group')
            g.user_set.add(user)
            # log user in
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, u'Welcome to Social FollowUp')
            return redirect('user_create')
    else:
        form = forms.UserSignupForm()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'user_signup.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

@login_required
@permission_required('')
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_form = forms.ListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            list_create = list_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'List {0} created'.format(list_create.list_id))
            return redirect(reverse('user_dashboard', args=(2,))) # 2 is just an example
    else:
        list_form = forms.ListForm()

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/create.html', {'list_form': list_form,         })


def user_dashboard(request, list_id):
    try:
        list_id = models.List.objects.get(pk=list_id)
    except models.List.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/view.html', {'list_id': list_id})
```

And finally my urls.py contains this:

```
url(r'user/signup/$', views.user_signup, name='user_signup'),
url(r'u/dashboard/(?P<list_id>\d+)/$', views.user_dashboard, name='user_dashboard'),
url(r'u/list/create/$', views.user_create, name='user_create'),
```

Basically I don't know how to make what I want to happen, happen. Whenever a user signs up and then creates a LIST object, the list_id is NOT being saved to the userProfile table I created. I'm not even 100% sure I need that table. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: how does your ListForm look ?

Comment: I just updated the post with my ListForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `user_create` view,

```
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_form = forms.ListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            list_create = list_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'List {0} created'.format(list_create.list_id))
            up, _ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, list_id=list_create)
            return redirect(reverse('user_dashboard', args=(2,))) # 2 is just an example

    #rest of the code
```

Basically, all you need to do is create a userprofile object.

Comment: I'm getting a `global name 'UserProfile' is not defined` error. I'm importing Models in my view.py file. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to do `from models import UserProfile`

Comment: Awesome! On a general note: why do I have to specifically import that model, even though I'm importing models? After I added that, and removed the signal from my models.py file it worked great. Thanks for helping me out a bunch lately, appreciate it!

Comment: well.. though you import the file, you need to import the model object specifically, this is a good feature, IMHO because it reduces confusion when there are conflicting names. You can even do `from .models import *`